# LINQ to Entity: How to add a method to select the expression LINQ, which will not be transferred to SQL. And will work with the result of the query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, mapping

I'm making the first steps in learning LINQ to Entity, I Use Entity Framework 5.

I have to write a LINQ expression because the structure database does not allow as easy to write in the style of lambda.

Without going into details, I have the following query.

```
    var query = from t1 in context.Table1 
                from t2 in context.Table2
                where t1.ExternalId = t2.Id &&
                      t1.Field1= "some value" &&
                      t2.Field1 < SOME_NUMBER
                select new MyCustomViewModel{
                      field1 = t1.field1,
                      field2 = t2.field1,
                      fieldBySpecificType = MyCustomMapper.Map<SomeType>(t1.field3),
                }
```

As you can see in the formation of the model is called a mapper that from a string representation deserialize importance to some class. LINQ and tells me that it can not translate this method in SQL expression.
As you can see my model contains fields from multiple tables, so I can `t collect it after.

I'm trying to find a solution that will be able to say that LINQ is unnecessary this method to translate into SQL. Something to sort attribute. But all my efforts were unsuccessful. Perhaps there is what is the architectural solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you first get your base query and make `ToList()` operation on the result, then you can apply your method which cannot be converted to SQL.

Comment: `var query = .... select new {a=t1,b=t2};`
and next step i do foreach and convet to my viewModel?
`var list = query.AsEnumerable().Select(q => new MyVuewModel{...});`
this solution you mean?